# [GYM][SB3] Custom Environment - How to limitate the actions of the agent depending on the current state

Tags: python, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am building a custom environment using Gym. Right now is working pretty well, but I want to solve the limitation of the actions.

I am using np.clip, so the agent is choosing one action based on the state, and the environment limit the action with np.clip.

Note: The custom environment is about a battery. Althought the agent must choose between [-Capacity,+Capacity], when the capacity is 0, the agent only can charge so the actions are limited (in this case [-100,0]. So the space of actions depends on the state.

How can I implement this feature (not using np.clip), so the space of actions is variable?
Am I looking at the problem in a wrong way?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I had a same question. Don't know if it will be useful, but you can just punish agent when it tries to do something except charging when capacity is 0.It is not really an answer to your question, but I hope it will help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you can get the current state, maybe you can try to put the observation into the step function, just like:

```
def step(self, action, obs):
```

then change your action according to your state. By the way, i'm a beginner in this area. i'm not sure if it will work. Hope it would help you